# Understanding Big-O notation as well as relations to derivatives

Tags: analysis, derivatives, asymptotics, partial-derivative

[The image of the assigment in question. (German)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqka9.png)

I currently need to understand the correlation of the Big O notation and derivatives.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^4$-Function and $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ are set. We define for $h<0$

$$D_hf(x,y) := \sum_{i=-1}^1 \alpha_if(x+ih,y)$$
$$\tilde{D}_hf(x,y) := \frac{f(x+h,y+h)-f(x+h,y-h)-f(x-h,y+h)-f(x-h,y-h)}{4h^2}$$

I need to find the coefficient $\alpha_i$ so that $D_hf(x,y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y) + O(h^2)$

As well as trying to prove that $\tilde{D}_hf(x,y) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y}f(x,y) + O(h^2)$

Currently i do not know how to go about this. I would probably need more understanding of Derivatives as well as the Big O notation. Any help would be appreciated to make me understand this. If i would have a point of reference to start out with.

Comment: Cay you share source of your question, please?

Comment: I would if i weren't written in German, i was trying to translate it good enough so i can deliver what you need to know, i could send the source, yet i do not know if you could translate it.

Comment: I also do not know German, but, send it, please. May be together we translate it better.

Comment: How do i send image files ? Do i just post it over into my original post ?

Comment: I added the image in question of the source of the assignment.